# Creating two instances of a class to run in seperate process from a single android activity

Tags: java, android

I have an android class Main Activity and Not Real dynamic. I would like to create two instances of NotRealDynamic in Main Activity class and make them to be in two separate processes.

Main Goal: To make V1 and V2 run in two separate processes.

My code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        TestClassIsInSeparateProcess();
    }

    public void TestClassIsInSeparateProcess()
    {
        NotReallyDynamic v1 = new NotReallyDynamic();
        NotReallyDynamic v2 = new NotReallyDynamic();
        assert(v1.getValue() == v2.getValue());
        v1.increment();
        assert(v1.getValue() != v2.getValue());
            // This only passes if v1 and v2 are in separate processes

    }
}
```

---

```
public class NotReallyDynamic {
    private static AtomicInteger _count= new AtomicInteger();


    public NotReallyDynamic() {
        _count.set(0);
    }

    public void increment() {
        _count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return _count.get();
    }
}
```

Can any one tell me how to run v1 and v2 in separate processes so my application does not crash?

Comment: separate process or separate thread?

Comment: seperate process.

Comment: does your app crash now? if so, post a stack trace.

Comment: We purposely made it that way. If v1 and v2 are on seperate processes then the value of v1 and v2 would be different and we sucessfully come out of the assert. I am unable to figure out how to run v1 and v2 on seperate precesses.

Comment: <android:process> is used to make an activity run as a separate process. But in a single activity to make the 2 instances of a class run on separate process, I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: oh, i see that the variable is static!

Comment: does the variable have to be static? if so, then you may have to somehow use a different http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html, if not, then the test will always pass.

Comment: Yea the variable has to be static.

Comment: you should make the methods static. looks like you will need to figure out how to use a different class loader. i don't know how to do that.